# PRAW: How to mark_as_read() with just the message ID?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I just have a list of messages IDs that I need to `mark_as_read()`, I don't need the message contents, just mark it as read.

Is it possible to mark them as read without fetching them first?

Answer (score 0):

Super late reply, sorry. In case you are still looking, here you go:

You should be able to create a new instance of a `message` object. Like so:

```
import praw
reddit = praw.Reddit('Bot-name')
msgIDs = ['id1','id2','id3']
for id in msgIDs:
    temp = reddit.message('id')
    mark_as_read(temp)
```

If you have any further questions feel free to ask.